# Is there a name for the verb "to have"?

Tags: verbs

If "to be" is the copula, is there any special name for "to have"?

Comment: Do you mean *to have an object* or *to possess a quality*? For example, "I have a laptop" versus "I have a cold" ?

Comment: Does it make a difference?   They seem to be grammatically the same to me.  The case I had in mind is actually different (in terms of the physics involved) from both, but seems to me to be grammatically identical to both: User has access to such-and-such a system.  Access is neither a physical object nor a property of the subject, but rather a property of the relationship between the person and the system, and any physical reflection of the access is stored in the system.

Comment: Yes, linguistically there is a big difference between having an object or having a quality or (in your comment) having a relationship. Having a quality or relationship is a state of being rather than a statement of possession. Consider "I'm hungry." In French, this uses the verb "to have," as in "J'ai faim" (= I have hunger). In Chinese, there is no linking verb. It's simply "wo3 e4 le" (= I hungry).

Comment: @rajah: I don't think you'll ever see it stated that _have_ is a linking verb in English, even though 'he was nauseous' is (arguably) an allowable if somewhat ambiguous paraphrase for 'he had nausea'. Perceptions as to where exactly 'having the qualities...' grades into 'being in nature ...' are not crystal clear, and this is reflected in the transitive verb of possession - link verb duality.

Comment: @iconoclast It does makes a difference which *have* you're talking about.  The senses of *have* are **not** grammatically identical.  Huddleston and Pullum break *have* down into three categories: **dynamic** *have* (as in "to have a fit"), which is always a  lexical verb; **perfect** *have* (as in "have been napping"), which is always an auxiliary verb; and **static** *have* (expressing obligation as in "I have to go now" or possession as in "I have enough money"), which is lexical for most speakers but auxiliary for some (particularly older BrE speakers).

Comment: @snailboat: yes the distinctions you make are indeed significant, but I'm saying the distinction between possessing and object and possessing a quality are not significant for my question, nor between having a disease and an object.  All of those are more or less forms of possession.

Comment: If Huddleston and Pullum claim that to be a comprehensive list, what do they say about having (possessing) a sandwich, or having a baby?  Surely (if one wants to find as many distinctions as possible) there are far more than three types!

Comment: @iconoclast **Syntactically**, I think all uses of *have* can be divided into those three categories.  One is always an auxiliary; one is always lexical; one is lexical for most speakers, but not all.  **Semantically**, you can come up with more categories.  (Note that "copula" is a syntactic label, not a semantic one.)

Answer (score 2):

The term **copula** is used in more or less strictly defined ways:

> In English, the verb be is sometimes referred to as "the copula," but
>   other verbs (identified in Observations, below) have a copular
>   function as well.

[[nordquist]](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/copulaterm.htm)

> **copula** ...
>   1. (Linguistics / Grammar) a verb, such as *be*, *seem*, or *taste*, that is used merely to identify or link the subject with the complement of a
>   sentence. Copulas may serve to link nouns (or pronouns), as in he
>   became king, nouns (or pronouns) and adjectival complements, as in
>   sugar tastes sweet, or nouns (or pronouns) and adverbial complements,
>   as in John is in jail

[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and
Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003]

> **cop·u·la**   a connecting word, in particular a form of the verb be connecting a subject and complement.

The last, loosest 'definition' certainly allows verbs like blush in 'the rose blushed pink' (which has semantic weight and which I'd call a 'link-like verb') - and possibly coordinators and prepositions. I don't recommend it. The other two usages are accepted (and partly contradictory).

Other incarnations of 'be' are as main verb (I am) and auxiliary (I am writing). 'Have' has incarnations as a main verb (I have enough money for a pint) when it is sometimes delexical (I'm going to have a bath) and an auxiliary (I have cut myself). But then so does 'do'. (Sundays, I do for Mr Jones / she did a jig on the table / I did go).

Comment: Are you implying that "have" is also *a* copula?  And therefore that there is some problem with people referring to "to be" as *the* copula?

Comment: It depends. If there is any "copula" in English (a debatable proposition), then it's _be_. Perceptual predicates like _seem, appear, feel, taste,_ etc. can appear in structures that look like the same thing, but have different properties. These verbs are only considered "copulas" in older textbooks which follow the Latin pattern (_copula_ is a Latin word and a Latin grammatical term).

Comment: @iconoclast: (1) I'm certainly not, and don't see where I've even hinted at that possibility (2) 'Copula' is an ill-defined term; John Lawler's comment here points to a deeper treatment going beyond argument about usage of terms and identifying different but similar-looking structures, which would seem preferable by far.

Answer (score 2):

*Have* is one of the three English **primary auxiliary** verbs. The other two are *do* and *be*. When used in constructions with other verbs, they show how the main verb is to be understood.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with my question.

Comment: Then I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I think there is some presupposition that "copula" is a special name for _be_ instead of a syntactic description, with the implication that there may be special names for other auxiliary verbs as well. Not unreasonable. But of course there aren't any English verbs like _be_ that are totally auxiliary; it deserves a special name if any verb does.

Comment: @JohnLawler: thanks for your comments, and yes I was presupposing that.  It was Matt Alexander who taught me that in (IIRC) Syntax 301 on 2nd or 3rd Frieze.  But I'm always open to correction: is that not really entirely correct?

Comment: Well, Matt was not always reliable on formal terminology that didn't impinge on his specialty, as I recall :-).

Comment: @JohnLawler by the way, if you put your explanation into an answer, I'll accept it as correct.